# How to exit a .sql from batch file

Tags: batch-file, db2

I am invoking a .sql file from a batch file but the control is not coming from the .sql after the job is completed. I need to press Ctrl+C to terminate the job. Is there a way I can terminate the sql job after it is complete.    I have this code in my batch file:

```
db2cmd -i db2 -o -vtf D:\Data\sql\UserProfile.sql 
and this is .sql file
connect to testdb user db2admin using db2admin;
update users set Type='B' where name like '%corp%';
terminate;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can agree the `db2cmd` documentation is a bit vague. You may want to try `db2cmd -i -c -w db2 -o -vtf D:\Data\sql\UserProfile.sql`